# url rewrite using asp.net routers with multiple parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting, url-routing

i am looking for url rewrite options using asp.net routers with multiple parameter.
i have parameters of category  and location.
i need to rewrite url with combination of both category and location or category alone or location alone. how to retrieve the search result based on category,location
Example

```
www.sample.com/flats-for-rent-india
www.sample.com/flats-for-rent
www.sample.com/india
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible unless you have unambiguous separator pattern that can delimit category and location. For example, let's say category and location will always be separated by say underscore(_) then you can have two patterns that would do the routing - `{term1}` or `{term1}_{term2}`. Again note that I am not saying category or location because term1 or term2 can be either and you have to sniff the actual values for the same.

Most probably, I would go with a single route such as `{query}` and then have a search algorithm that will search for given query term against both category and location.

If you are probably looking at exact match i.e. {query} should give either location or category or combination then you have to probably implement your search accordingly. For example,

1. Search the query term against available categories - if match found we are done.
2. Search the query term against available location - if match found we are done.
3. Split the query term with possible separators (e.g. hyphen(-), underscore or space) - search parts against category/location. For example, "flats-for-rent-india" would be split into following pairs

   1. flats & for-rent-india
   2. flats-for & rent-india
   3. flats-for-rent & india
      so now you have to try each pair against available categories and locations - this would probably give you a match at #3.